# Check the efficieny of the code

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two files

tree_0 of this form:

```
443457316403167232  823615  Tue Mar 11 18:43:57 +0000 2014  2   
452918771813203968  26558552    Tue Mar 11 21:10:17 +0000 2014  0   
443344824096538625  375391930   Tue Mar 11 11:16:57 +0000 2014  9   
452924891285581824  478500516   Tue Mar 11 11:38:14 +0000 2014  0
```

trees.json

```
{"reply": 0, "id": 452918771813203968, "children": [{"reply": 0, "id": 452924891285581824, "children": []}]}
```

Now, I have to go though file trees.json and find the id in tree_0 and if it is present then i have to perform some task.

I have loaded the tree_0 using readlines().
Both the files are very big (10gb in size). I have written a code but would like to know if this code is ok or there can be something more efficient. 
as for each id this is luking into the whole tree_0 (while loop).

```
import json
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)

fr=open('tree_0','r')
lines=fr.readlines()
l=len(lines)

# to find children of trees, this works fine
def get_children(node):
    stack = [node]
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        stack.extend(node['children'][::-1])
        yield node 

f = open('trees.json','r') 
linenum=0       
for line in f:
     d = json.loads(line)
     child_dic={}
     if (linenum<1000):
         for child in get_children(d):
             if child not in child_dic.keys():
                 i=0
                 while (i< l): # checkwhetherthis makes it slow as my files are large
                     data=lines[i].split('\t')
                     # search for id in the tree_0 file
                     if str(child["id"])==str(data[0]): 
                         print "Perform some task here"
                     i=i+1
```

Comment: Question might be more suitable for - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: given that the files are called `tree`, one would almost suspect they already have some type of key sorted structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing a lot of unnecessary and inefficient work here. First, since you only need the IDs, you do not have to store the entire `tree_0` file in memory. Instead of each time iterating though all the lines and extracting the ID, do it just once when you load the file. Also, you can store the IDs in a `set`. This will dramatically improve look-up speed.

```
with open('tree_0') as f:
    all_ids = set(int(line.split('\t')[0]) for line in f)
```

If you *do* need the other field from `tree_0` as well, you could make it a dictionary, mapping IDs to those other fields. This will still have much faster look-up than looping the list each time.

```
with open('tree_0') as f:
    all_ids = dict((int(items[0]), items) for items in (line.split('\t') for line in f))
```

With this change, the rest of your code boils down to this:

```
with open('trees.json') as f: 
    for line in f:
        d = json.loads(line)
        for child in get_children(d):
            if child["id"] in all_ids:
                # optional: get other stuff from dict
                # other_stuff = all_ids[child["id"]]
                print "Perform some task here"
```

---

Update: If the "IDs" in `tree_0` are not unique, i.e. if you have multiple lines with the same ID, you could use, e.g. a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) mapping IDs to lists of other attributes, like this

```
with open('tree_0') as f:
    all_ids = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        items = line.split('\t')
        all_ids[int(items[0])].append(items)
```

Then, in the other part of the code, just perform the task for all the entries in the list:

```
            if child["id"] in all_ids:
                for other_stuff in all_ids[child["id"]]:
                    print "Perform some task here", other_stuff
```

Comment: No but, I have to use the other fields (column corresponding to data[0]) further.

Comment: thanks a lot. This appears to be much faster.

Comment: When i run the code, I have duplicate entries for the keyword. How to remove duplicate entries in the above edit.

Comment: @Saurabh What exactly do you mean? Do you have multiple lines with the same ID in `tree_0`, or do you have multiple entries with the same ID in `trees.json`? And in the latter case, do you want to have unique entries per `line`, or for all `trees.json`?

Comment: I have multiple lines with the same id in tree_0.

Comment: Sincle the value of key is coming as list. how to access let us say tuple 3. Actually i cannot even seperate it with comma as some of my field may contain comma.

Comment: @Saurabh I don't know. I just split by any whitespace, which was good enough to get the ID, but to separate the other fields you might have to split by `\t`, depending on your actual data.